# How to fetch only single type using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to fetch only those company for which there is only one type. I am using  using Oracle 12C. Below is the sample dataset

[image]

Result Set:-

[image]

Some one please help me on this.

Comment: If you only need to fetch the companies, why do you still need multiple rows per company in the output? One row per company should suffice.

Comment: Another thing: Your post is tagged both for oracle11g and oracle12c. What is your actual version? That may make a big difference; a potential solution uses the `match_recognize` clause, but that is only available since oracle 12.1 (so - not in oracle 11g). Please make sure you always tag with the correct version for your real-life db.

Answer (score 2):

```
select companyid, min(type_) as type_
from   [table_name]
group  by companyid
having min(type_) = max(type_)
;
```

Replace `[table_name]` with your actual type name. Note also that I used `type_` (with an underscore) for the column name. I hope your column name is not `type`, which is a reserved keyword; if it is, change it.

A possible alternative is to use `having count(distinct(type_)) = 1` - but that is a poor solution. It requires a `distinct` operation within each group (by `companyid`). By contrast, `min` and `max` are much easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.companyid = t.companyid and t2.type <> t.type
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to compare `MIN(TYPE)` for each company with its `MAX(TYPE)`. If they're the same then it only has one `TYPE`.

```sql
SELECT CompanyId, Type
FROM myTable
WHERE COMPANYID IN (
  SELECT COMPANYID
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY COMPANYID
  HAVING MIN(TYPE) = MAX(TYPE)
)
```